# Git clone a specific tag/version from public github repository and push to private repository

Tags: git, github, push, pull

I am trying to clone a specific version from a public GitHub repository. This version I would like to modify, bring in my own settings and push it to a private hosted git repository.

From time to time I would like to pull newer versions from the public GitHub again and merge it with my own modifications and push again to my own private repository.
I don't know how to achieve this.

I added the public GitHub repo to my own git by
`git remote add github https://github.com/xyz/xyz.git`
But I don't know how to pull a specific version and how to push it to my own repository. Getting the error: `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`

What is the best practice in such a case? I am sure others have the same goal.

Comment: What are the contents of your "own git"? You cannot easily add another repo to one which already has stuff.

Comment: It sounds like you want to [work with a fork](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks).

Comment: Yes, it is like a fork, but with the private repository not hosted on GitHub. The content of the own repository would be configuration settings, docker composition, plugin...

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that you cannot add the history of another repo to your repo which already has files and its own history.

If you want to use another project with your own, the easiest way is to add it with the package manager of the language you are using. All package managers I have worked with have syntax to install from a git repo, including directly from a specific branch or tag.

If you need to make changes, you can fork the other repo and then use that one instead of the main repo. You should find ways to support the desired behavior in your own repo first, though.